# how do I create variable that is a random character from a list

Tags: python, variables, error-handling

`list1 = ["yummy", "brown", "cool"]`
`list2 = ["fox", "putin", "pluto"]`
`while True:`
`ch1 = input("Choose the First Character of Your Password, yummy_brown_cool: ")`
`ch2 = input("Choose the Second Character of Your Password, fox_putin_pluto: ")`
`password = ch1 + " " + ch2`
`break`
`if ch1 not in list1 or ch2 not in list2:`
`print("invalid password")`

this is the code. now I wanna create 2 variables (guess1 and guess2) which are from list1 and list2. they then check if guess1 + " " + guess2 == password, and prints what guess1 is and guess2 is. would be so thankful if you could help

Comment: You should try to create a MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  Play around with the formatting a bit too, and welcome to SO! :)

Answer (score 2):

To choose a random `str`ing from a `list`, you can use the function `random.choice`:

```
>>> random.choice(["Hello", "World"])
'Hello'
```

You can do a similar thing for a random `char`acter from a `str`ing:

```
>>> "Hello"[random.randint(0, len("Hello")-1)]
'e'
>>> random.choice("Hello")
'l'
```

Comment: Or just *random.choice('Hello')*

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to pass a string as argument, thank you, I'll edit the answer